# Perl regex S&R when search token is a var that contains reserved chars

Tags: regex, perl

Consider this:

```
my $var = "${SOME_VAR}"

my $string "In this text ${SOME_VAR} will be replaced with X"

$string =~ s/$var/X/g;

print "\nprocessed string = <".$string.">";
```

returns

```
processed string = <In this text ${SOME_VAR} will be replaced with X>
```

i.e. the replace does not take place.

However, if $var does not contain a reserved character ($), the replace DOES take place:

```
my $var = "SOME_VAR"
/* everything else the same */
```

returns

```
processed string = <In this text ${X} will be replaced with X>
```

But I do not know how to escape reserved characters when they are contained within a variable, i.e. when the search token is not explicit but parametarized.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: -1. Your code doesn't do what you said it does. Please update with code that actually produces the results you claim.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. After fixing the three syntax errors, the code produces «`XIXnX XtXhXiXsX XtXeXxXtX X XwXiXlXlX XbXeX XrXeXpXlXaXcXeXdX XwXiXtXhX XXX`», not «`In this text ${SOME_VAR} will be replaced with X`» as you claim

Comment: (And that's assuming `use strict; use warnings;` isn't used as it should be.) I will retract the -1 once you fix it.

Comment: @ikegami. Yeah.. just saw that by mistake.. removed  my comment..

Comment: The `${foo}` syntax is a soft reference, even inside strings. You are indirectly assigning the value of `$SOME_VAR` to `$var`. If `$SOME_VAR` is undef, you get an empty string, translating to *match always* in the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string contains `$` which has a special meaning.. You can use `\Q` and `\E` to get it work..

```
$string =~ s/\Q$var\E/X/g;
```

**\Q disables pattern metacharacters until \E**

Comment: @foampile.. I think ikegami is right.. when I ran your code with this regex, I got some weird output.. HAven't you posted your complete code??

Answer (score 0):

The `${foo}` syntax is a soft reference, even inside strings. You are indirectly assigning the value of `$SOME_VAR` to `$var`. If `$SOME_VAR` is undef, you get an empty string, translating to *match always* in the regex.

Single quotes or escaping the `$` solves the problem in addition to using `\Q` as Rohit Jain noted.